# How to get fields from child table when parent table is queried in jpa

Tags: java

I have 2 tables question and question option. Question has a composite key. When I query question by an id how do i get question options as well. How can I ensure that I getting the question options as well. As of now I'm only getting the questions. Should I change the mapping or should I add some properties

Question

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"assessment"})
public class Question implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private QuestionAssessmentKey questionAssessmentKey;

    public QuestionAssessmentKey getQuestionAssessmentKey() {
        return questionAssessmentKey;
    }

    public void setQuestionAssessmentKey(QuestionAssessmentKey questionAssessmentKey) {
        this.questionAssessmentKey = questionAssessmentKey;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name =  "assessmentId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Assessment assessment;

    private String questionText;

    private String questionURL;

    private QuestionStatus questionStatus;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name="assessmentId", referencedColumnName = "assessmentId"),
            @JoinColumn(name="questionNumber", referencedColumnName = "questionNumber")
    })
    private List<QuestionOption> questionOptions;

    public List<QuestionOption> getQuestionOptions() {
        return questionOptions;
    }

    public void setQuestionOptions(List<QuestionOption> questionOptions) {
        this.questionOptions = questionOptions;
    }

    public Assessment getAssessment() {
        return assessment;
    }

    public void setAssessment(Assessment assessment) {
        this.assessment = assessment;
    }
    //    private int questionNumber;
    private QuestionTypes questionType;
//Getters and setters
}
```

QuestionOptions

```
@Entity
public class QuestionOption {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int questionOptionId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name="assessmentId", referencedColumnName = "assessmentId"),
            @JoinColumn(name="questionNumber", referencedColumnName = "questionNumber")
    })
    private Question question;

    private Character questionOption;

//Getter and setter
}
```

QuestionAssessmentKey

```
@Embeddable
public class QuestionAssessmentKey implements Serializable {

    private int questionNumber;

    private String assessmentId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot fetch all the data in a single query since it is a one-to-many relationship between questions and question options. However when you call `getQuestionOptions` on the fetched `Question` entity, it should load and return the corresponding set of options.

Comment: what if there is only a @ManyToOne mapping

Comment: In that case you could use [`FetchType.EAGER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/FetchType.html#EAGER) to accomplish this

Comment: FetchType.EAGER on the @ManyToOne in QuestionOption?

Comment: Yeah. But that wouldn't resolve your issue because it'd just make Hibernate load the corresponding Question entity eagerly when you are resolving a QuestionOption entity by ID; it can't be done the other way around though since each question can have multiple corresponding options.